# Looking for a late 1970's fiction book for 6-8 yr olds in UK about a boy in the East who has two animal companions

Tags: identification-request

I read this in 1978/9. I think it was fairly new and chose it as a 'free reader' in school. We moved house and I never got to finish it! This is what I recall of it:

- Green cover
- Hard book
- Main character a boy
- Animal companions - 2? Possibly dragon or panda? Monkey? One of them really daft.
- Set in China/East - folk tale like but had a modern feel
- Humourous
- Some sort of mission
- Disastrous but amusing events. Particularly remember something about a city, split milk, city walls
- Occasional line illustrations, gestural style but not cartoons
- May have been read on Jackanory (BBC) or schools radio.

Comment: Could this be an abridged, or possibly modernised version of 'Journey to the West'? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West#Notable_English-language_translations

Comment: There is a complete list of Jackanory episodes on Wikipedia, something might ring a bell there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jackanory_episodes